# Getting JSLint to break a build in visual studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, jslint

I have integrated JSLint (http://javascriptlint.com) into my projects post build - but can't seem to get it to fail the build if an error/warning occurs?

Currently JSLint is ran from a .bat file that gets executed on post-build

Is there a param I can pass in to tell JSLint to fail the build if error/warning is encountered?

Thanks in advance folks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JSLint extension for VS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/961e6734-cd3a-4afb-a121-4541742b912e) has an option to automatically display JSLint warnings in the error list. In addition, you can run JSLint on build and cancel the build if a rule is violated.

Or, if you would like to continue running JSLint through a batch script, you could force MSBuild to raise an error depending on the return exit code of the script:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="jslint.bat" ContinueOnError="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>

    <Error Text="Error running JSLint" Condition="'$(ErrorCode)'>'0'" />
</Target>
```